# Does KaOS distribution provide software manager to install any software?

Tags: linux, arch-linux

**KaOS** which is based on arch-linux but since I'm familiar with *debian* so it would be so easy if distribution provides Software Manager.
Does KaOS distribution provide **Software Manager** to install all softwares?

Comment: It has Octopi GUI and pacman CLI. But [KaOS is NOT based on Arch](https://kaosx.us/about/based/), nor is it unstable  (like Arch-based distros *are*, no matter what bug-reportiong-lovers say). Packages are more thoroughly tested, similarly in a way to Solus KDE, and thus, although one can use pacman to install arch packages, that is strongly advised against. Flatpak, appimages and [KCP](https://kaos-community-packages.github.io/) are better ways to get more software if one must. **The fact that one doesn't hear a lot about this distro on this site is partly due to its lack of problems.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called Octopi and from there you can search for and install software.